# File input inside fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox pop-up that contains a file input (`input type="file"`). Prior to fancybox 2, the fancybox contents stayed inside the `form` element in the DOM when the fancybox was displayed. Now that I've switched to fancybox 2, this is no longer the case; the fancybox contents are detached from their position in the DOM and relocated to a position outside of the `form`. Consequently, when the `form` is submitted the file selected in the file input is not uploaded with the request.

I don't have a good sense of whether the previous version of fancybox intentionally supported leaving the fancybox contents in their position in the DOM, or if that was just the way it worked without necessarily being intentional to solve the type of problem I'm having.

Regardless, is there a way I can ensure that fancybox 2 keeps the contents of the fancybox inside the `form`?

Comment: do as suggested : move the whole `form` to fancybox. BTW previous versions of fancybox (not the latest v1.3.4) used to "clone" elements into fancybox (and keep the originals in the DOM structure) but starting with v1.3.4 and v2.x+ elements are **moved** to fancybox and a placeholder is left instead.

Comment: I don't think I can move the whole `form` to be inside the fancybox, because I have multiple fancyboxes that contain `form` fields for a single form. I'll have to think more about it; maybe there's a variation that will work for me.

Comment: Looks like my solution is going to be to *not* use fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you were to wrap the entire contents of your <body> tag with a FORM element, the behavior of a third party plugin shouldn't be trusted to insert its contents inside of it.

Many plugins will insert its necessary content *after* everything else, similar to (or exactly like)...

`$('body').append(...)`

Obviously, in this case your `form` would be null of any fancy content.

Unfortunately for you, this may cause some unfancy rearranging, but you should include your entire `form` in the fancybox content page itself. Not only should this solve the problem, but it is just a much *safer* solution.

Comment: Wrap the body with form? WHAT? Hard to tell what is the point of the answer

Comment: I believe it says..."wrap the *contents* of the body tag"...and it is just a hypothetical statement anyways to get my point across...

Comment: I see... However, I still don't see what you are suggesting

Comment: @JuanMendes : he is suggesting to move the whole `form` to fancybox, which it would be the right thing to do, otherwise the fields (moved to fancybox) will be pulled out of the `form` tag.

Comment: @andbeyond I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure if I can make it work in this particular case because I have multiple fancyboxes that contain fields for the same `form`.

Comment: Like you said above, not using Fancybox or using just one is the solution, the other option would be to modify Fancybox or write your own version (its really not hard).